# PyDev: how to turn off code completion for method arguments

Tags: django, pydev

An example would be when I'm typing:

```
admin.site.reg...
```

The completion when I commit / apply the suggestion includes not just the method name (register()), but also "`(model_or_iterable, admin_class)`" -- half of which I have to go back and delete.

All I want committed / applied is the method name with empty parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When applying the completion, leave Ctrl pressed (i.e.: instead of applying with Enter, apply with Ctrl+Enter -- although in that case you'll have to add the parenthesis).

Comment: Thank you.  I suppose my problem, then, would be that I don't know when I need to hold down Ctrl and when not to; it's inconsistent.  Other methods only commit the name with empty parentheses.